# Converting dictionaries in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to convert all values of some dictionaries that are nested in another dictionary.
I want to convert:

```
{0: {'n': 1}, 1: {'s': 0, 'n': 2}, 2: {'s': 1}}
```

To this:

```
{0: {'n': '?'}, 1: {'s': '?', 'n': '?'}, 2: {'s': '?'}}
```

I tried this:

```
for key, value in new_dictt:
    new_dictt[key][value] = '?'
```

But it did not work.  I've been googling but have not found a way to convert all values of all dictionaries within another dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we go:

```
old_dict = {0: {'n': 1}, 1: {'s': 0, 'n': 2}, 2: {'s': 1}}

new_dict = {key: {k: '?' for k in dct} for key, dct in old_dict.items()}
print(new_dict)
```

Which yields

```
{0: {'n': '?'}, 1: {'s': '?', 'n': '?'}, 2: {'s': '?'}}
```

This uses two nested dict comprehensions.